# Symfony3 Doctrine select with many-to-many

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have 3 entities: *User*, *Category* (of posts) and *Group*. Category has *allowedGroups* field with many-to-many relation with groups. User also has *groups*. I'm looking for the simplest way show to current user only these categories which has at least one of the user's groups in *allowedGroups*. I tried to fetch all categories and "manualy" filter them in controller, but it is not perfect way I think. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function in the user entity which would be getCategories, which would do a for each loop on the $user->getGroups() and array_merge all the categories of each group then use array unique to remove duplicates.